# postgres json array elements and null returns

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, null, jsonb

I have a json column in a table in postgres that includes an array of objects e.g.

```
{"BlockData":[{"Name":"George","Age":"54","Height":"1.75"}, {"Name":"Mario","Age":"35","Height":"1.90"}]}
```

I am using a Select query and want to access the Name object and the value pair of the Name (George and Mario). What I am trying to to is the following:

```
select jsonb_array_elements(jsondoc_->'BlockData')->>'Name' from BlockData;
```

What I get in return is

> ```
> "ERROR:  cannot extract elements from a scalar
>
> SQL state: 22023"
> ```

From what I could discover is that this issue occurs because at some rows the return is NULL. Can you please advise how can I overlap this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try to Filter them?

```
t=# with t(jsondoc_) as (values('{"BlockData":[{"Name":"George","Age":"54","Height":"1.75"}, {"Name":"Mario","Age":"35","Height":"1.90"}]}'::jsonb),('{"BlockData":null}'))
select jsonb_array_elements(jsondoc_->'BlockData')->>'Name' from t
where jsondoc_->'BlockData' <> 'null';
 ?column?
----------
 George
 Mario
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Hi Vao no i haven't tried it. I did now and it works fine thank you.